# Numerical solution of equation with free parameters

Tags: equation-solving, manipulate

I have an equation which is not analytically solvable,
 thus I need to solve it numerically. 
But, this equation has some free parameters which I want to replace them with some numbers after solving the equation
.
 Let me ask a very simplified version of the question, 
then I can solve the original one by the help of this simplified version. 
I have an equation with the form of $a\space x^5+b\space sin(x)+3=0 $.
Now, I want to `plot the root of this equation` in the `a-b coordinate` system. 
In another word, 
I want to fix the root and see how it behaves by changing our free parameters, $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [`ContourPlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot3D.html):

```
ContourPlot3D[a x^5 + b Sin[x] + 3 == 0, 
  {a, -1, 1}, {b, -1, 1}, {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, 
  AxesLabel->{"a","b","x"}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, use [`ContourPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot.html) to show combinations of `a` and `b` that make a given `x` the root and vary `x` interactively using [`Manipulate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html):

```
Manipulate[ContourPlot[a x^5 + b Sin[x] + 3 == 0, {a, -1, 1}, {b, -1, 1},  
     FrameLabel -> {"a", "b"}], 
  {{x, Pi/2}, -2 Pi, 2 Pi, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. How can I transform this plot into two-dimensional a-b coordinate system for constant x?

Comment: @Mehrdad, please see the updated version.